# react-native-maps inside Tab not working

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I'm having trouble displaying my `<MapView />` inside a Tab. I'm using [react-native-scrollable-tab-view](https://github.com/skv-headless/react-native-scrollable-tab-view)

The `<MapView />` won't display in the map even after using : `...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject`. I can display the map only if I put a fix height. For example: `height: 500`.

Here is what my sample tab screen looks like.

```
styles = StyleSheet.create({
  tabContent: {
    flex: 1,
  },

  map: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
  },
});

class HomeTemporary extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollableTabView
        renderTabBar={() => <ScrollableTabBar />}
      >
        <ScrollView tabLabel="List" style={styles.tabContent}>
          <Text>Content Tab One</Text>
        </ScrollView>
        <ScrollView tabLabel="Map" style={styles.tabContent}>
          <MapView
            scrollEnabled
            style={styles.map}
            provider={MapView.PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
            initialRegion={{
              latitude: 25.2048493,
              longitude: 55.2707828,
              latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
              longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
            }}
          />
        </ScrollView>
      </ScrollableTabView>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: See picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely about what? If the map inside the view, the view component must also specify the absolute value of the width and height. In your case for `tabContent`.

Comment: Hey there, wouldn't making the tabContent `flex: 1` would make the height of the tabContent View to be full height? I updated my question with screenshot to explain better. I would like the MapView to fit within the tabContent component

Comment: Assign height using `Dimensions.get('window').height`. This is a normal practice, what do not you like?